# Run powershell scripts from c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script with c# in my app. the problem is the the script doesn't do the job if I run it with c#, but it does the work if I run it by hand.

That's the script: `DISM /online /Enable-Feature /Featurename:NetFx3 /All`

The script enables Framwork 3.5 on windows server. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/install-or-uninstall-roles-role-services-or-features)

My code:

**NuGet:** `System.Management.Automation`

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create()) 
{ 
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("DISM /online /Enable-Feature /Featurename:NetFx3 /All ");

    // begin invoke execution on the pipeline
    IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke();

    // do something else until execution has completed.
    // this could be sleep/wait, or perhaps some other work
    while (result.IsCompleted == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for pipeline to finish...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // might want to place a timeout here...
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
}
```

I used examples from [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

Note: my app run as admin.

Comment: what is the error? try wrapping it with a try-catch block.

Comment: There is no error, it isn't enables the 3.5 feature. After a few seconds the console says "finished"

Comment: Check `PowerShellInstance.HadErrors`.  If that's true, check `PowerShellInstance.InvocationStateInfo.Reason` for the exception, if that's null check `PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error` for non-terminating error records.  If none of those give the information you need `PowerShellInstance.EndInvoke(result)` will give the output of the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add admin privileges into your powershell script, sometimes that helps

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -windowstyle hidden -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -noexit -File "$ScriptPath"' -Verb RunAs}"
```

You can save your powershell command in ps1 file and give the path as a parameter ($ScriptPath). This powershell command is tested on C# via running your specified code. Hope this helps. If not then I advice to use Process from C# System.Diagnostics namespace.